# Cancellation property in matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just found a question which is based on a doubt I have carrying for over 10 years.

If $ACC^t=BCC^t$        : $C^t$ means transpose of $C$

Is

- $A=B$
- $AC=BC$

Sorry if this is a trivial question.

All I know is if AC=BC, then A=B if C is invertible.
If C is invertible, so is $C^t$. Then both the options will be satisfied if C is invertible.

Comment: If $A = B$, then $AC = BC$.

Comment: If it work well in the invertible case, the next thing is to check $C=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your first assertion:

$ACC^\mathsf{T} = BCC^\mathsf{T}$ is equivalent to $(A-B)CC^\mathsf{T} = O$.
If $CC^\mathsf{T}$ has a non-trivial kernel, then there are always $A\neq B$ satisfying this equation.

Concerning your second assertion:

Suppose $xCC^\mathsf{T}=0$. If our base field is $\mathbb{R}$, then $\|xC\|^2=xCC^\mathsf{T}x^\mathsf{T}=0$, hence $xC =0$. Doing this separately for all rows in $A-B$ shows $(A-B)C=0$.

If the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ however, we can use rohit's example $C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, so $CC^\mathsf{T} = O$. Thus, in this case the second assertion does not hold.

If you're using another field, please feel free to specify so in the comments.

Comment: What if A, B and C are non zero?

Comment: @O.L. and Matt Pressland You're right, I was a bit to quick. Let me adjust my answer.

Comment: Please specify the field. Because if field is complex no. take   2 X 2 maatrix  upper row c = [1 i] lower row = [0 , 0] . Then c X Ctranpose = 0 so we can take specific A and B s.t. AC is not eqaul to BC

Comment: Although the field is not mentioned, assume it to be rational. I just want to clear my concepts.

Comment: The rationals are a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, so if there is no counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, there is certainly no counterexample in $\mathbb{Q}^{m\times n}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.